# Why is Bazel run_shell not placing arguments correctly?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have rule `a`:

```
def _a_impl(ctx):
    src = ctx.actions.declare_file("src.txt")
    ctx.actions.write(src, "nothin")
    dst = ctx.actions.declare_file("dst.txt")
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        outputs = [dst],
        inputs = [src],
        command = "cp",
        arguments = [src.path, dst.path]
    )
    return [DefaultInfo(files = depset([dst]))]

a = rule(
    implementation = _a_impl,
)
```

For some reason, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: /home/erran/example/out_dir/BUILD:9:1: error executing shell command: '/bin/bash -c cp  bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/src.txt bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/dst.txt' failed (Exit 1) bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash -c cp '' bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/src.txt bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/dst.txt
```

It looks like Bazel isn't parsing the arguments correctly. As you can see, the actual bash command tries to `cp '' <src> <dst>`

I also tried just formatting the copy command itself, which worked fine:

```
ctx.actions.run_shell(
    outputs = [dst],
    inputs = [src],
    command = "cp {} {}".format(src.path, dst.path)
)
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the [documented semantics](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#run_shell) of passing string to the `command` parameter of `run_shell`. Something like this should work:

```
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        outputs = [dst],
        inputs = [src],
        command = "cp $1 $2",
        arguments = [src.path, dst.path]
    )
```